# Cartesian Product of list with mixed value types

Tags: python

I have run into a problem when using itertools in python. I have a list like:

```
listEx = ['a1', 'b1', [['lxt11', 'tag11', 'url11'], ['lxt12', 'tag12', 'url12']], 'd1']
```

When using `list(itertools.product(*listEx))`, the strings get broken up like they are iterables themselves (I know they actually are, I don't want them to be used that way though.) Example output:

```
[('a', 'b', 'c', ['lxt11', 'tag11', 'url11'], 'd'), ('a', 'b', 'c', ['lxt11', 'tag11', 'url11'], '1')...]
```

I want the output to be like:

```
[('a1', 'b1', ['lxt11', 'tag11', 'url11'], 'd1'), ('a1', 'b1', ['lxt12', 'tag12', 'url12'], 'd1')]
```

This only happens when the starting list is:

```
listEx=[['a1'], ['b1'], [['lxt11', 'tag11', 'url11'], ['lxt12', 'tag12', 'url12']], ['d1']]
```

Because I'm dealing with large amounts of data, it is time expensive to iterate through all the lists and make each individual entry a list itself. Is there a better way to go about it?

Thank you.